# Marker on google maps not shown (google maps with react)

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

Can't setup markers on my map. line is prefectly drowing, but not Markers. Which way is correct to add it? they just not dispaying on the map. I take part of this code from https://jsfiddle.net/8kwdf0v7/16/ and there on the map everything fine

```
    const MyMapComponent = ({ center, zoom,children }) => {

    const ref = useRef();

    let marker1, marker2;
    let poly, geodesicPoly;
    const [myMap, setMap] = React.useState();

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (ref.current && !myMap) {
          setMap(new window.google.maps.Map(ref.current, {
            center,
            zoom,
            disableDefaultUI: true,
        }));
        }
      }, [ref, myMap]);

    useEffect(() => {

        if (myMap) {
            marker1 = new window.google.maps.Marker({
                myMap,
                draggable: false,
                position: { lat: 40.714, lng: -74.006 },
            });
            marker2 = new window.google.maps.Marker({
                myMap,
                draggable: false,
                position: { lat: 48.857, lng: 2.352 },
            });
    
            const bounds = new window.google.maps.LatLngBounds(
                marker1.getPosition(),
                marker2.getPosition()
              );
            
              myMap.fitBounds(bounds);
              poly = new window.google.maps.Polyline({
                strokeColor: "#FF0000",
                strokeOpacity: 0.2,
                strokeWeight: 5,
                map: myMap,
              });
    
              update();
        }

        
    },[myMap]);


    const update = () => {
        const path = [marker1.getPosition(), marker2.getPosition()];
        poly.setPath(path);

        const heading = window.google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(
          path[0],
          path[1]
        );
      }

      console.log(children)

      return (
        <>
          <div ref={ref} id="map" />
          {React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
            if (React.isValidElement(child)) {
              // set the map prop on the child component
              // @ts-ignore
              return React.cloneElement(child, { myMap });
            }
          })}
        </>
      );
};

export default MyMapComponent;
```

I try pass Marker as child element in container like this, but this not help me, how to debug this?

```
 let position = { lat: 40.714, lng: -74.006 }
    <Wrapper libraries={["geometry"]} apiKey="Q" render={this.renderS()}>
          <MyMapComponent center={this.center} zoom={this.zoom}>
            <Marker position={position}/>
            </MyMapComponent>
        </Wrapper>
```

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the issue? The link you provided is pure js, it would be helpful if you can also provide a snippet of your own code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in MyMap var

```
marker1 = new window.google.maps.Marker({
            **map:myMap**,
            draggable: false,
            position: { lat: 40.714, lng: -74.006 },
        });
```